How to update the ViewLayer without warnings?
I want to update the view layer but I am getting this warning.
Should I ignore it or handle it, How?
related to: How to hide/unhide objects in a particular ViewLayer?
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def update_view_layer(scene):
    if view_layer := scene.view_layers.get("NewViewLayer"):
        view_layer.update()


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(update_view_layer)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(update_view_layer)

Original exception was:
object address  : 000002D1EF41C6A0
object refcount : 1
object type     : 00007FFE760E9050
object type name: RecursionError
object repr     :
lost sys.stderr


Why should you update the view layer? Maybe you should not? apparently calling a view_layer.update triggers the depsgraph_update_post which in turn recursively calls the update again thus causing a recursion problem. So it seems not correct to do that. Can you give more details of what you are trying to do and why you need this update so it won't be an xy problem :) maybe call the update not from depsgraph.

Avoid running functions recursively
is_running = [False]

@persistent
def update_view_layer(scene):
    if is_running[0] is True: return
    is_running[0] = True

    if view_layer := scene.view_layers.get("NewViewLayer"):
        view_layer.update()

    is_running[0] = False


But maybe in the first place, it's not good practice to call a function inside a depsgraph callback that triggers a depsgraph callback again?

Also I don't quite get why the boolean needs to be inside a list/array? why won't a simple is_running=True/False work?

Sometimes, you have to refresh again in the refresh function, but it's better to avoid doing this.

is_running=True/False doesn't work because it assigns local variables and not global variables. Or you can use global is_running

ok thank you for the info :)
